# Pythonic way between str() and quotation marks

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to learn the pythonic way of coding when working with the language, and came across a [solution that uses empty strings in two different ways](https://exercism.io/tracks/python/exercises/simple-cipher/solutions/46ade1ed61584bdd8fbc2be9a1af3098):

- On line 5: `self.key = key or ''.join(choice(alphabet) for _ in range(100))`
- On line 8: `output = str()`

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq), the method `str()` returns an empty string when no parameters are passed onto it.

Is there any difference between these two options from a functional point of view and what would be the preferred way of using an empty string in code?

Comment: I would say it is more idiomatic to use `''` to initialise an empty string.

Comment: Consider this: someone can assign something else to the name `str`; then you don't know *what* `str` will return, if it is even still callable. (Though there could be a slew of other problems if `str` gets re-assigned.) Literals cannot be overridden; `''` is an empty `str`, period.

Comment: `str()` is an unfamiliar way to do familiar thing. `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`